Woocommerce: hide “Price display suffix” when the VAT is zero
is there a way to hide the “price display suffix” of the products when the VAT is zero?
(I’m currently doing some test on a local test site).
For example, the shop is set in Germany, the products have 19% vat included in their price. The displayed price is let's say “115€ included VAT”.
Customer XY is from the US (under settings / taxes I set the US in the zero taxes table with 0%); he sees the prices without the 19% and that's perfect.
The displayed price is “96,64€ included VAT” – even if the VAT is zero and actually isn't there.
Is there a way to hide the label / tag “INCLUDED VAT” when the VAT / tax is zero?
Thanks
Davide

This probably isn't easy because the users usually aren't logged in, so the system doesn't know when to hide that.  Are you using some sort of GeoCoding function to determine what price to display, because you may want to hook into that to show/hide the suffix?

Hi Tony, that's a good point (geolocation) and definitely something I should consider; thank you. I might have found a solution for the vat label issue. More soon..
